# What happens if I assign Google's IP address to my PC?

Tags: wireless-networking, ipv4

For instance, if I assign an Ip to my PC and that IP address is of some other website (say Google.com), then what happens? Traffic gets diverted to my system or what?

Comment: Does traffic get routed to you, no, you won’t have any Internet at that point.

Comment: You will lose internet access until you switch back to your usual IP. The routers that make up the internet know how and where to route traffic and will continue to route traffic to the proper destination.

Comment: The same reason applies to why you can't put someone else's address from one country on your mail and expect to receive it at your home address somewhere else. There is a lot of background stuff that goes on beyond "just an address" and no one is going to randomly route traffic to a place it is never expected to go.